# DNS Resolver does not contain answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, scripting, dns

I'm trying to automate some of the tasks with python. I have to chcek if some domains are still in ours DNS servers. So searching through stack i found script with dns.resolver and tryied to suit it to my needs. 
So, the script looks like this:

```
import socket
import dns.resolver


mylist=[]
with open('domainfile.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        mylist.append(line)
length = len(mylist)


resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers=[socket.gethostbyname('dns.example.com')]

for i in range(length):
    for rdata in resolver.query(mylist[i], 'CNAME') :
        print(rdata.target)
```

My `domainfile.txt` looks like this:

```
domain1
domain2
domain3
[...]
```

And error message i recived is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "dnspython.py", line 20, in 
>       for rdata in resolver.query(lista[i], 'CNAME') :
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1053, in query
>       raise_on_no_answer)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 236, in **init**
>       raise NoAnswer(response=response)
>   dns.resolver.NoAnswer: The DNS response does not contain an answer to the question: domain1\010.example.com. IN CNAME

If I just insert my domain inside **if statement** instead of iterate through the **mylist** I get what I need. But when I try to do it through the list it adds to my domain **\010** and then nothing happens. 
Can you help me with this? 
Thanks!

Comment: What's the encoding of the file `domainfile.txt`? I think this might be the problem.

Comment: If you want to check the encoding on a unix-system, run the command: `file <filename>`

Comment: I suspect the issue is more likely unstripped line endings.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for quick answer :)
domainfile.txt is just `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` file. Do you recommend to change it to utf-8 or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems expected according to the docs: http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.14.0/dns.resolver.Resolver-class.html#query

> Raises:
>
> ...
>
> - NoAnswer - the response did not contain an answer and raise_on_no_answer is True.

The reason it's happening is probably because you haven't removed line endings from your domains.

---

Here's how I'd do it.

```
import socket
import dns.resolver


with open('domainlist.txt') as f:
    my_list = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers=[socket.gethostbyname('dns.example.com')]

for domain in my_list:
    try:
        q = resolver.query(domain, 'CNAME')
        for rdata in q:
            print(f'{domain}: {rdata.target}')
    except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
        print(f'{domain}: No answer')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
That solved my problem. I abbadon `readlines()` at the beginning and don't know why :)